# Como capturar parâmetro em formulário com enctype="multipart/form-data"?

Tags: java, html, formulário, file-upload, glassfish

Estou com problemas para capturar os parâmetros de um formulário HTML com enctype="multipart/form-data", consigo fazer upload de uma imagem através do formulário, porém não consigo capturar texto digitado no formulário.

O formulário está assim:

```
<form method="post" action="UploadServlet" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select file to upload: <input type="file" name="file" size="60" /><br />        
    Enter text: <input type="name" name="teste"/><br />        
    <br /> <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Meu Servlet para capturar os dados enviados por POST está assim:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

@WebServlet("/UploadServlet")
@MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024*2, // 2MB
                 maxFileSize=1024*1024*10,      // 10MB
                 maxRequestSize=1024*1024*50)   // 50MB
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Name of the directory where uploaded files will be saved, relative to
     * the web application directory.
     */
    private static final String SAVE_DIR = "uploadFiles";

    /**
     * handles file upload
     */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // gets absolute path of the web application
    String appPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("");
    // constructs path of the directory to save uploaded file
    String savePath = appPath + File.separator + SAVE_DIR;        

    //Capturar campo teste do formulário
    String teste = request.getParameter("teste");
    System.out.println("Parametro capturado: " + teste);

    // creates the save directory if it does not exists
    File fileSaveDir = new File(savePath);
    if (!fileSaveDir.exists()) {
        fileSaveDir.mkdir();
    }

    for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
        String fileName = extractFileName(part);
        part.write(fileName);
    }

    request.setAttribute("message", "Upload has been done successfully!");
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/message.jsp").forward(
            request, response);
}

/**
 * Extracts file name from HTTP header content-disposition
 */
private String extractFileName(Part part) {
    String contentDisp = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
    String[] items = contentDisp.split(";");
    for (String s : items) {
        if (s.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
            return s.substring(s.indexOf("=") + 2, s.length()-1);
        }
    }
    return "";
  }
}
```

Quando o atributo enctype="multipart/form-data" está no formulário não consigo capturar texto, pois o request.getParameter() sempre retorna um valor nulo. Uso servidor GlassFish 4.1, e estou iniciando meus estudos em back-end. Desde já, gradeço a ajuda de todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problema resolvido, encontrei a solução na documentação da Oracle:

[The fileupload Example Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glraq.html#gmhbq)

Se alguém se deparar com esse mesmo problema, fica aqui registrado a solução que funcionou em meu projeto.